# Tests for predictive models with autoregressive neural networks

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, autoregressive, validation

I'm working with time series predictions with NNAR autoregressive neural network models (p, P, k) and I'm doubtful for the validation of my models. After making the predictions, I'm selecting those that showed lower MASE and RMSE in my test set.

My question is that, in traditional time-series models like ARIMA (for example), there is a lot of testing to do, such as ADF, Box-Pierce, Ljung-Box, Shapiro-Wilk, coefficient significance, etc.

Are there any tests or other analysis I should do on neural network models in general? In the articles and books I read I did not find any, only cross-validations and analysis of accuracy measures like RMSE.

My results were very good, but I would like to know if I need any additional strengths.